# addChildAt function in flex seems to be not working

Tags: apache-flex, events, keypress

i am working on a flash player and in that i am adding functionality of going to full screen and then coming back to normal screen for that i am displaying a button for going to full screen and then a button to come back to normal screen and toggling between normal and full screen i change the buttons for full screen and normal screen it works fine if i toggle b pressing that icons/buttons but when i come back to normal screen from full screen the addChildAt function doesn't seems to be working as my code for that event is

```
public function replaceIconFs():void
{
    var indexReplace:Number = partTwo.getChildIndex(exit_fullScreen);
    partTwo.removeChild(exit_fullScreen);
    partTwo.addChildAt(view_fullScreen,indexReplace);
    fs=false;
}
```

and the elements are defined as

```
<mx:Image id="sepFscreen" width="0" source="{sep}"/>
            <mx:Button id="view_fullScreen" width="28" height="31"
                       click="view_fullScreen_clickHandler(event)" paddingLeft="0"
                       paddingRight="0" paddingTop="2" skin="{FullScreenButtonSkin}"
                       toolTip="View Fullscreen"/>

            <mx:Button id="exit_fullScreen" width="28" height="31"
                       click="view_fullScreen_clickHandler(event)" paddingLeft="0"
                       paddingRight="0" paddingTop="2" skin="{ExitFullScreenButtonSkin}"
                       toolTip="Exit Fullscreen"/>
```

now i need to know that why that`partTwo.addChildAt(view_fullScreen,indexReplace);` is not seemed to be working 
also i want to mention the same code works for other player but not for this
thanks in advance

Comment: Could you clarify what worked fine?  Also, what is the "other player" where this code works?

Comment: <mx:Image source="{sep}" id="sepFscreen"/>
    <mx:Button id="view_fullScreen" width="30" height="31"
         click="view_fullScreen_clickHandler(event)" paddingLeft="10"
         paddingRight="10" paddingTop="2" skin="{FullScreenButtonSkin}"/>
    
    <mx:Button id="exit_fullScreen" width="30" height="31"
         click="view_fullScreen_clickHandler(event)" paddingLeft="10"
         paddingRight="10" paddingTop="2" skin="{ExitFullScreenButtonSkin}"  />

this code works fine as it is same as previous one and i have 4 players having different flow. one player is the problem else is working